# Windows.open using onclick cannot open multiple page

Tags: html, window.open

I am trying to open two individual files, now my problem is why only can open 1 file (file/w1.pdf), another file (file/w2.pdf) I cannot open. Below is my sample coding:

```html
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('file/w1.pdf','','width=700,height=700'); window.open('file/w2.pdf','','width=700,height=500');"
>Click Here</a>
```

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve it problem. Thanks.

Comment: It's like spamming users with multiple new windows is generally considered to be an awful user experience that is easily exploited by people wanting to spam advert popups and thus is blocked by browsers.

Comment: Also the second parm should be the name of the window  and different or _blank

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I now which one is suitabled method to replace my codes?

Comment: Have two links the user can click one at a time

Comment: @mplungjan Yes. User click one at a time can show more links